# How to get Session's value in a class object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have assigned session a custom class's object like:

```
Services Obj = getServiceDetails(3); //getting all data of Service where Id = 3
Session["ServiceObj"] = Obj;
```

Now I want to assign its value to same class's another object in a model class. I don't know how to do it.

I tried but it is not valid way.:

```
Services oldObj = <Services>Session["ServiceObj"];
```

Pls Help me. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `Services oldObj = (Services)Session["ServiceObj"];`

Comment: @Igor, It would be nice if you post your comment as answer.So I can accept it.

Comment: Done (see my answer below)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct type cast requires round brackets:

```
Services oldObj = (Services)Session["ServiceObj"];
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `Services oldObj = (Services)Session["ServiceObj"];`

instead of `Services oldObj = <Services>Session["ServiceObj"];`

Answer (score 1):

```
not <Services> use (Services) for casting
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it with your Class like this

```
Services obj = (Services)Session["ServiceObj"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also refactor the typed data retrieval using a generic, e.g. using an extension method, like so:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T GetTypedVal<T>(this HttpSessionState session, string key)
    {
        var value = session[key];
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is T)
            {
                return (T)value;
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                     string.Format("Key {0} is not found in SessionState", key));
    }
}
```

Which you can then use for reference and value types, like so:

```
    Session["Value"] = 5;
    var valResult = Session.GetTypedVal<int>("Value");

    Session["Object"] = new SomeClass() { Name = "SomeName" };
    var objResult = Session.GetTypedVal<SomeClass>("Object");
```

Answer (score 0):

to get value from session you should cast it.

```
Services oldObj = (Service)Session["ServiceObj"];
```